# How to fix Routing in Marionette when using Browserify

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, browserify

I have a Marionette project and I try to make it work with Browserify.
My app.js:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

var Controller = require("./controller");
var Router = require("./routes");

var App = new Marionette.Application();

...

App.addRegions({
    header: "#header_region",
    side_menu: "#side_menu_region",
    main: "#main_region",
    footer: "#footer_region"
});

...

var controller = new Controller({});

App.addInitializer(function(options){
    ...
    var router = new Router({
        controller : controller
    });
});

App.on("start", function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
});

App.start({});

module.exports = App;
```

My controller.js:

```
var headerView = require('./header/view');
var sideMenuView = require('./side_menu/view');

module.exports = function() {
    var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        showHome: function(){
            var header_view = new headerView();
            App.header.show(header_view);
            var side_menu_view = new sideMenuView();
            App.side_menu.show(side_menu_view);
        }
    });
    return Controller;
}
```

My routes.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var Route = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes: {
            '': 'showHome'
        }
    });
    return Route;
}
```

My browserify command:
browserify app.js -o bundle.js

For some reason, I can't get into my showHome function inside the controller.
So when I go to my site, I get an empty page without any errors in the console.

Does anybody know what am I missing?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: how do you start your application then in your html? 
I'm rather new to browserify but I found the --standalone option to be very helpful:
for instance, `browserify app.js -s App -o bundle.js` would make the object your app.js `exports` available on `window.App`